# Reversing an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

If I have an array like this:

```
1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11
```

What is the best way to reverse the array so that it looks like this:

```
11 9 4 7 9 16 9 4 1
```

I have the code below, but I feel it is a little tedious:

```
public int[] reverse3(int[] nums) {
    return new int[] { nums[8], nums[7], nums[6], nums[5], num[4],
                       nums[3], nums[2], nums[1], nums[0] };
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Use a loop to swap each of the elements in the first half with the elements in the second half.

Comment: If i used void that means i wont be able to use the return statement in this method right?

Comment: That is true. You can either reserve the exist array which may or may not be returned. Or you can return a copy.

Comment: Based on the idea you already had, I would hazard a guess that you are very experienced in development, so I will point out an easy alternative. Just do what you want in a reversed for-loop, instead of actually reversing the array. `for (int i = someArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { doStuff(someArray[i]); }
    reversedArray[j++] = firstArray[i];
}`

Answer (score 71):

[`Collections.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) can do that job for you if you put your numbers in a `List` of `Integers`.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11);
System.out.println(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11]
[11, 9, 4, 7, 9, 16, 9, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more thanks

Comment: Please see the edit to the answer.

Comment: Why instantiating a new ArrayList? Arrays.asList() already returns a List.

Comment: Thanks @cypressious, I was under the impression that Arrays.asList would return an unmodifiable list. Corrected that.

Comment: Arrays.asList actually returns a Frozen list in the sense that you cannot add or remove any element from that newly created List. However you are allowed to do inplace element modifications.

Answer (score 69):

If you want to reverse the array in-place:

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array));
```

It works since [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns a write-through proxy to the original array.

Comment: Though an old answer it costed me some time to figure out... This does not work for the op as int[] is an object and Arrays.asList(array) will return List<int[]> and not List<int> (which is impossible anyway) so actually a List with exactly one entry which is reversed the same. This is true for all primitive arrays!

Comment: public int decToBinary(int n) 
    { 
        // array to store binary number 
        int[] binaryNum = new int[1000]; 
   
        // counter for binary array 
        int i = 0; 
        while (n > 0)  
        { 
            // storing remainder in binary array 
            binaryNum[i] = n % 2; 
            n = n / 2; 
            i++; 
        } 
         return Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(binaryNum));
    } ----------------  Gives an error -->   error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int
         return Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(binaryNum));

Answer (score 33):

If you don't want to use `Collections` then you can do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
  int temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
  array[array.length - 1 - i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it worth to put `array.length / 2` part to outside before the for-loop? It will be recalculated every iteration, I believe.

Comment: @JinKwon I believe that the compiler will enhance it that way, you can try it out with javap

Comment: @JinKwon To clarify this, I didn't mean javac, I was talking about the JIT compiler, the optimisation that happens at run time.

Answer (score 12):

I like to keep the original array and return a copy. This is a generic version:

```
public static <T> T[] reverse(T[] array) {
    T[] copy = array.clone();
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(copy));
    return copy;
}
```

without keeping the original array:

```
public static <T> void reverse(T[] array) {
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array));
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. I like the fact that you didn't change the original array, instead you returned a new array.

Comment: Doesn't work for array of Primitives though

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
public int[] reverse3(int[] nums) {
    int[] reversed = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        reversed[i] = nums[nums.length - 1 - i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

My input was:

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12`

And the output I got:

`12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`

Answer (score 5):

You could use org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils :
`ArrayUtils.reverse(array)`

Answer (score 3):

Or you could loop through it backeards

```
int[] firstArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
int[] reversedArray = new int[firstArray.length];
int j = 0;
for (int i = firstArray.length -1; i > 0; i--){
    reversedArray[j++] = firstArray[i];
}
```

(note: I have not compiled this but hopefully it is correct)

Answer (score 3):

In place reversal with minimum amount of swaps.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
    a[a.length - 1 - i] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
public int[] reverse3(int[] nums) {
  int[] numsReturn = new int[nums.length()]; 
  int count = nums.length()-1;
  for(int num : nums) {
    numsReturn[count] = num;
    count--;
  }
  return numsReturn;
}
```

Comment: @RodrigoKossmann.. Or you can just use: - `numsReturn[count--] = num`

Answer (score 2):

you messed up

```
int[] firstArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
int[] reversedArray = new int[firstArray.length];
int j = 0;
for (int i = firstArray.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    reversedArray[j++] = firstArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void swap(int[] arr,int a,int b)
 {
    int temp=arr[a];
    arr[a]=arr[b];
    arr[b]=temp;        
}
public int[] reverseArray(int[] arr){
    int size=arr.length-1;

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){

        swap(arr,i,size--); 

    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will reverse in place the array between indexes `i` and `j` (to reverse the whole array call `reverse(a, 0, a.length - 1)`)

```
    public void reverse(int[] a, int i , int j) {
        int ii =  i;
        int jj = j;

        while (ii < jj) {
            swap(ii, jj);
            ++ii;
            --jj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like this answer because it avoids calling the .length method inside the loop and doesn't constantly calculate len - 1 - i; it works for any range of the array and uses swap instead of a temp variable. But there's no reason to use the duplicate variables (ii & jj); you can just use i & j directly. I'd swap(ii++, jj--) and avoid the extra lines.

Comment: Note also that it only works if i < j; if you want it to always work you could assign ii = min(i,j) and jj = max(i,j).

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to use a temporary variable, you can also do like this:

```
final int len = arr.length;
for (int i=0; i < (len/2); i++) {
    arr[i] += arr[len - 1 - i]; //  a = a+b
    arr[len - 1 - i] = arr[i] - arr[len - 1 - i];   //  b = a-b
    arr[i] -= arr[len - 1 - i]; //  a = a-b
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code would help:

```
int [] a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  System.out.println(a[i]);
```

Comment: @Begueradj - it looks like an answer to me - not necessarily a good one, but it's an answer.

Answer (score -3):

you can send the original array to a method for example:

after that you create a new array to hold the reversed elements

```
public static void reverse(int[] a){

int[] reversedArray = new int[a.length];

for(int i = 0 ; i<a.length; i++){
reversedArray[i] = a[a.length -1 -i];


}
```