# Reversing an array by java mechanism

Tags: java, arrays

I am a new bie to the world of java , I was going through array , in an interview it was being asked from me write a code to reverse an array , I have gone through the following approach..
using Apache commons ArrayUtils class , but please advise how can the same thing be achieved through java itself, below is the my approach

```
 int[] iArray = new int[] {101,102,103,104,105};
     String[] sArray = new String[] {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}; 
     System.out.println("Original int array : " + Arrays.toString(iArray));
     ArrayUtils.reverse(iArray); System.out.println("reversed int array : " + Arrays.toString(iArray)); 
     System.out.println("Original String array : " + Arrays.toString(sArray)); ArrayUtils.reverse(sArray); System.out.println("reversed String array in Java : " + Arrays.toString(sArray));
```

Output :-

```
Original int array : [101, 102, 103, 104, 105] reversed int array : [105, 104, 103, 102, 101] Original String array : [one, two, three, four, five] reversed String array in Java : [five, four, three, two, one]
```

Please advise how we can achieve the same thing in java itself.

Comment: What have you tried *without* using a utility library? I assume you know how to set a value in an array and how to retrieve one... think how you can go from there.

Comment: This question has all sort of answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678781/reversing-an-array-in-java?rq=1. Do some search before you put a questions.

Comment: You know, Apache commons is open source, you can check the ArrayUtils' source code in order to understand how they do it: http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.java.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse an array like this:

```
public void reverse(Object [] a){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++){
        Object temp = a[i]; // swap using temporary storage
        a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
        a[a.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

It's worthy to note that it doesn't matter if the array length is an odd number, as the median value will remain unchanged. I have to admit that I haven't tested this but it should work.

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/3qqRAm)

Answer (score 1):

Here i wrote an example:

http://ideone.com/OUA4r9

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"one", "two", "three"};
        String[] reverse = new String[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            reverse[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse));
    }
}
```

Output

> [one, two, three]
>   [three, two, one]

Comment: `count` is unnecessary and it doesn't change the values of the original array.

Comment: the count is necessary if he wants to save the old array and get a new reversed array ...so he can work with both

Comment: But you have your `i` value. Instead of iterating backwards, use `i` instead of count and set the value to the array at `[array.length - i - 1]`

Comment: http://ideone.com/5LVBN7

Comment: Ok, you are right could be are other solution. thank you.

Comment: Your solution was good though. :) And you showed me what ideone.com was +1

Comment: :) yeah is a great page, isn it?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. Edit your answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<iArray.length/2; i++)
{
    int temp;
    iArray[i] = temp;
    iArray[i] = iArray[jArray.length-i-1];
    iArray[jArray.length-i-1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't reverse the original array, which appears to be what's required.

Comment: @JonSkeet that better?

Comment: use a swap not an assignment. `swap(iArray[i], iArray[jArray.length-i-1]);` That would be much cleaner.

Comment: @JonSkeet One can copy back the contents of the reversed array to the original one.

Comment: @Paranaix: Yes, one can. But that's not really a good approach, and the code given doesn't actually answer the question. (Changing one variable to refer to a different array isn't the same thing as changing the contents of the array.)

Comment: @SamIam `iArray = jArray;` wont work as it will just set the reference to the new array. Youll have to change the values of the old array!

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple to write, just think through the task logically.

The array has indices from 0 to N. To reverse the order, the element at index 0 needs to swap places with index N, 1 with N-1 and so on.

You are finished when every pair of indices i(0...N) k(0...N) has experienced exactly one swapping operation.

This can be expressed with very minimal logic in code:

```
for (int i=0, j=array.length-1; i<j; ++i, --j) {
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}
```

And thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in Java to reverse the given array.

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(sArray));
```

Comment: Here's an example of yours working http://ideone.com/46Ups9.  Only other issue is that it won't work with primitive types.  So in order for the int array to work it will have to be Integer objects - I +1 you also